Looking through previous file versions and restoring hunks?
I want to be able to see a list of previous versions of a file in a git repo, select one of them to see a diff, and choose which parts from that version I want to restore, something like git checkout -p. I looked a bit at Neogit and Diffview's documentation but haven't figure out a way to do this, I'm wondering if anyone here has.

With tpope/vim-fugitive, here's the workflow I would use:

edit a file
:0Gclog load commits touching that file into the quickfix list
Navigate to one you like and run :Gdiffsplit to diffsplit against the current version. This is going to show you all the changes between the old and current version; if you just want to see what changed in the commit, after opening the quickfix entry press <Enter> to open the commit itself.
Use the usual do/dp/etc. from :help copy-diffs move diffs to the worktree

